PowerApps How can I untick a checkbox when ticking another check box from different fields from a SharePoint list
I have an existing app and the users have requested a new field to be added to be called Collect
example
first check box is chkDeliver
the new check box field will chkCollect
Is there a way to untick one check box when the other is ticked (like how a radio field works)?
I do realise that it would work better as one choice field using a radio style in the app, but the App has been functional for a long time and already has live data in SharePoint and a lot of PowerAutomate flows that use the "Deliver" field.
I am hoping for a way to get functionality in the App without changing all the flows.
I have searched various YouTube videos but all are explaining how to do this when the values are from the same SharePoint column choice field. I have not found any for using different SharePoint fields.
I have tried using a variable to hold the check box value when opening the screen as follows:
Set(
varDeliver,
chkDeliver.Checked
)
also tried
If(chkDeliver.Checked = true,
Set(
varDeliver,
true
),
Set(
varDeliver,
false
))
I created a test label on the screen with text value as varDeliver to see if it sees correctly true or false but this doesn't work (its always showing false).
I also tried both updating the "OnCheck" value of ChkCollect to update a variable (set as the default on chkDeliver) using "set" and using "UpdateContext"
so far I am not getting any correct results.
I am fairly new to PowerPlatform and I suspect that this is actually simple and I am over complicating it.
Can anyone help me with this please?
Thank you

You can achieve this by two ways
Approach 1: Reset the other

Set OnCheck property of chechbox1 as Reset(checkbox2)
Set OnCheck property of chechbox2 as Reset(checkbox1)

Approach 2:
Initialising variable and switchings its value by doing the following steps:
For 1st Checkbox

Set OnCheck property as UpdateContext({flag: 1}). This will help to identify the Checkbox by assigning it's flag as 1.
Set OnUncheck as UpdateContext({flag: 0})
Set Default property as flag = 1. It means if the flag is 1 then only keep it checked, so whenever flag is other than 1 it will uncheck it automatically.

For 2nd Checkbox

Set OnCheck property as UpdateContext({flag: 2}). This will help to identify the Checkbox by assigning it's flag as 2.
Set OnUncheck as UpdateContext({flag: 0})
Set Default property as flag = 2. It means if the flag is 2 then only keep it checked, so whenever flag is other than 2 it will uncheck it automatically.

